# Limit the comments view to node author

Tags: comments

Is it possible to add a visibility restriction to article comments? (For instance, only the poster can view comments.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way by which you can elegantly do this from a custom module would be:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_view_alter().
 */
 function my_mod_node_view_alter(&$build) {
   $node = $build['#node'];
   if (isset($build['comments'])) {
     // It is good practice to allow the administrator to see comments of all nodes.
     $build['comments']['#access'] = 
       user_access('administer comments') || ($node->uid == $GLOBALS['user']->uid);
   }
 }
```

Comment: this code hides the comments which are not made by the poster of any posts, but it doesnt show the comments made on his/her own posts.. any way to alter the codes?

Comment: Fixed a small typo in the reference to the PHP $GLOBALS variable. Can try again now?

Answer (score 2):

I can't find contrib module for your task. I suggest you to write some code.
In template.php add [template_preprocess_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7)

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables){
  global $user;
  $variables['some_var'] = ($user->uid == $variables['node']->uid) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Than in node.tpl.php

`<?php if ($some_var): ?>
 <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>
 <?php else: ?>
 <?php print 'You have no access to see comments'; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>`

Please tell me, if be some problems.

Comment: Even though your approach should work to hide comments, print statement will print the text at the very top of the browser because output has not started yet (we are PREprocessing right ?)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using panels. In the content visability section you can set that up.

Comment: Can you expand a little on how this is done?